# .setPreviewDisplay(holder) creating NullPointer exception

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have created a custom camera application and it works perfectly fine on almost all devices but it seems to be crashing on devices listed as **other** in the developer portal. These users are all giving me bad reviews I would like to solve this problem but it is very hard for me to figure it out, because it works perfectly on all the devices I own.

`camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);` is what is causing the error and it is occurring when the app launches.`

```
public class CamPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
SurfaceHolder holder;
Camera camera;
private List<Camera.Size> sizes;

public CamPreview(Context context, Camera camera)
{
    super(context);
    this.camera = camera;
    holder = this.getHolder();

           holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    holder.addCallback(this);

}

private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height)
{
    Camera.Size result=null;
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
            if (result==null) {
                result=size;
            } else {
                int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                int newArea=size.width*size.height;

                if (newArea>resultArea) {
                    result=size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
{
    if (holder.getSurface() == null) return;

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size optimalSize = getBestPreviewSize(width, height);
    try{
    parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width,optimalSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);

    }
    catch (NullPointerException a)
    {

    }
    camera.startPreview();


}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{

    try
    {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        camera.release();
        camera=null;
        Log.d("FrontCam", "Error creating surface: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        camera.release();
    }


}
}
```

logcat:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.me.frontcam.CamPreview.surfaceCreated(CamPreview.java:136)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:552)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6883)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1921)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1528)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1264)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

how I open the camera

```
void initCamera()
{
    //check for front camera
    if(Camera.getNumberOfCameras()>1)
    {

     camera= Camera.open(1);
        try
        {
                camera.cancelAutoFocus();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException a)
        {

        }


        try{

            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException a)
        {
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }

    }

    else
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Sorry but you cant use this app")
                .setMessage("You do not have a front camera")
                .setPositiveButton("Quit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    //Quits application
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       finish();
                    }
                })

                .show();
    }



}
```

I then call the initUI method where the CamPreview constructor is called

```
void initUI()
{
    white= new ImageView(this);
    imgShoot = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgShoot);
    imgShoot.setOnClickListener(imgShootOnClick);

     frmPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frmPreview);
    preview = new CamPreview(this, camera);

    frmPreview.addView(white);
    white.setImageResource(R.drawable.aperture_opening);
    frmPreview.addView(preview);
    frmPreview.bringChildToFront(preview);  

}
```

Ive looked at both of these and they did not solve my problem
[Android - cam.setPreviewDisplay(holder) running into IOError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825129/android-cam-setpreviewdisplayholder-running-into-ioerror)

[.setPreviewDisplay(holder) throwing null pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984542/setpreviewdisplayholder-throwing-null-pointer-exception?lq=1)

Any help appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 3):

Please check if you have added the required permission in your manifest, this worked for me

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Answer (score 2):

If you are crashing with a `NullPointerException` in the `surfaceCreated()` method shown above, then it should be obvious what your problem is: `camera` is `null`.

Since you are passing `camera` into the constructor of `CamPreview`, you will need to investigate how you are calling this constructor.

Comment: I just added more code. My camera is initiated before I call the constructor so I still dont see what could be wrong

Comment: @WillJamieson: Well, first, if the user cancels out of your "you need 2+ cameras" dialog, `camera` will be `null`. Second, assuming that `Camera.open(1)` is a front-facing camera is completely wrong. For example, on a Nexus 7, there is only one camera, which is front-facing.

Comment: So would opening camera by using the answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779002/how-to-open-front-camera-on-android-platform solve my problem?

Comment: @WillJamieson: [This specific answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4767832/115145) will open a FFC, if there is a FFC. However, the device might not have an FFC, so you still need to do a bit better job of dealing with that scenario.

Comment: well if I change it to  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" /> then the app wouldnt be able to download unless the device had a FFC

Comment: @WillJamieson: In theory, yes. Your problem, though, is "devices listed as other in the developer portal". I am under the distinct impression that this is a fig leaf for "devices that do not have a legitimate license for the Play Store, where the manufacturer has installed a pirated copy". All bets are off with such devices and whether or not `<uses-feature>` will be handled properly. So, *in addition* to the `<uses-feature>`, you would need to handle this case in code, at least if you are worried about crashes on these devices, which is the point behind your question.

Comment: What Is your solution? change it to <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" /> ?

Comment: @DT The solution is to confirm at runtime that the camera exists, and not to rely solely on <uses-feature> elements.

Answer (score 0):

I will advice you to check first, if either your `camera` object or your `holder` object are null in your `surfaceCreathed` method.
You should also check if you have already opened your camera: `camera.open()`